# Free UK Company Database

Tags: data-request, business

I have a company review and rating website but I need a faster way to populate my database with UK Companies. What I need is the full company name, address and telephone number only so I can import it in CSV format. I have tried companies house but does not provide the contact number within their databases. Where could I find a free open up to date database so it can be imported into my website?

Comment: Unfortunately, you do have to pay for the CSV and XLS version, do you know is a way of me being able to download via the API? Is there a way I can import the data somewhere from the API, then download it into CSV or XLS format? Thanks Mark

Answer (score 2):

Seems like OpenCorporates is exactly what you're looking for. It describes itself as:

> The largest open database of companies in the world

https://opencorporates.com/companies/gb is the listing of UK companies from which you can download data via the XML and JSON APIs for free and it seems like you might need to pay to get it in CSV or XLS formats

Comment: So does OC have the phone numbers of companies that have no such information on CH? If so, how did you obtain it?

Comment: There is no way to download anything for free from opencorporates.com.  It's a paid service.

Comment: Why do you say that? It looks open enough to me